# How can I get the form input picture to save to my drive as a cropped square?

Tags: python, image, flask, crop

I'm making a social media site. When the user inputs there profile picture, I want to make it so that I can take that image, crop it so that it is 125x125 then save it. How can I do this?

I've looked at a few other stackoverflow posts, and it doesn't seem to be working...

```
def save_profile_picture(form_picture):
    random_hex = os.urandom(8).encode('hex')
    _, f_ext = os.path.splitext(form_picture.filename)
    picture_fn = random_hex + f_ext
    picture_path = os.path.join(current_app.root_path,     'static/profile_pics', picture_fn)

    output_size = (125, 125)
    i = Image.open(form_picture)
    w, h = i.size
    i.crop((0, 0, 125, 125))
    i.save(picture_path)
```

Doing this doesn't give me the correct picture saved, it's just the same picture again... What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: try: `new_img = i.crop(); new_img.save()`